# How do I change a user's password in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

How do I change a user's password in Oracle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> alter user <user> identified by <password>;

Answer (score 9):

Expanding the @Randy answer, you also can use the following (undocumented) sentence to set a password without knowing the real one:

```
alter user <user> identified by values '<encrypted password>';
```

You can get the encryped values for passwords on `PASSWORD` column on the table `DBA_USERS`. Its nice, for instance to migrate a database to another one and copy the password without knowing it. The password owner have not to be disturbed.

In some scenarios (for example, if password complexity verification function has been enabled) you have to use the following one:

```
alter user <user> identified by '<newpassword>' replace '<currentpassword>';
```

As reference, you can check in the [*Oracle® Database SQL Reference*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm) the [ALTER USER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm) command, and the [INDENTIFIED BY](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm#sthref5700) clause.

Comment: I had to use double quotes around the password, otherwise I got ORA-00988: Fehlende(s) oder ungültige(s) Kennwort(wörter)
00988. 00000 -  "missing or invalid password(s)"

Comment: From my side, I had to remove the quotes :
alter user YourDBUserName identified by YournewPassword replace YourOldPassword;

Answer (score 8):

The downside of using the alter user command to change a password is that the command (and the password) is transmitted in clear text over the network.

If you are not using any other methods to ensure a secure connection (ssh, Oracle advanced security, etc.) I would advise to instead use the password command.

Since Oracle 8 you have the option to use **password user_name** or **passw user_name**

```
SQL> passw scott
Changing password for scott
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
```

There is a [post by Pete Finnigan](http://www.petefinnigan.com/ramblings/passwords_in_clear_text.htm) about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much what Randy said. If you need some other commands, try going to http://www.ss64.com/ora/. There's a nice list of command divided in categories such as cluster, users and you can find pretty much anything you need by browsing around that website.